# How to use python to sign in to orcid.org

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, mechanicalsoup

### Problem

I'm trying to use mechanicalsoup to login to [ORCID](https://orcid.org/signin), but I'm unable to access the login form.

### Attempts

This should be very straightforward:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open('https://orcid.org/signin')
browser.select_form('form[id="loginForm"]')
```

However, this results in a `LinkNotFoundError`.

I also tried simply finding any form with a non-stateful browser:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
login_page = browser.get('https://orcid.org/signin')
print(login_page.soup.find_all('form'))
```

And that yields an empty list, so it's not even seeing the form in the return. This confused me, as `print(login_page.soup)` returns everything, and I could see the form in there.

### Question

How can I access the form and successfully login? (I'm fully open to using something other than mechanicalsoup, too.)

I imagine it has something to do with the fact that you can switch login methods on the page itself. See here:

[image: orcid login page image]

I'm very far from a frontend expert, but when I inspect the page, I imagine that's governed in some way by the `events` seen here:

[image: orcid login page inspector image]

If anyone can provide any help or insight, I'd certainly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

While the login form on https://orcid.org/signin appears to be a straightforward form that does not require JavaScript, generating the login page itself *does*.

You can test this by visiting the login page in your browser with JavaScript disabled (e.g. see [instructions for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/disable)). When I do this, I see a blank page with the following message:

> For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript. Here are the instructions for enabling JavaScript in your web browser.

Unfortunately, it looks like MechanicalSoup will not be able to help you here, since it does not support JavaScript. You may need to try a fully-fledged browser emulator like Selenium.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense. Thanks for the idea!